# Images in assets/images/ not showing up in AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a few assets in the app/assets/images/ folder in my RoR app. These images are available in my local environment as /assets/image.png, and they work when I deploy to Heroku (using as test env), but the app is now running on AWS (Elastic Beanstalk) and the image assets give me a 404. The css and js files work just fine, it's only the image files that do not work. Below are the relevant pieces of production.rb - and it should be noted that production.rb (running on AWS - images do not work) and test.rb (running on Heroku - images do work) are exactly the same.

**production.rb**

```
config.eager_load = true

# Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

# Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
# Apache or NGINX already handles this.
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
# config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

# Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.precompile =  ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb']
```

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Not in the exact sense that I was hoping, but I did find a workable solution. For inline images I just use the image_tag method i.e.

`<%= image_tag 'profile.png' %>`

And for images in css, I renamed the css file to .css.erb, and use asset_path i.e.

`<%= asset_path 'profile.png' %>`